# how to set border in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have some css code which i have used for html pages which goes like this

```
<style>
    body{
        border-width: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #045FB4;
        margin:0px;
    }
</style>
```

In IE and Chrome it is displaying exactly when i use the page as a pop-up to my website. But same page if i use in firefox its bottom border is not to bottom it is 8% above mean not to exact corner.

I need suggestion how to set border if am using firefox to display pages.

I have tried

```
 margin-bottom:-65px;//in css
```

it is fine works very good in firefox but to other browsers it adds with a scroller.

Comment: Try this `border: 1px solid #045FB4;`

Comment: if I understand correctly, try giving `padding: 0px;`

Comment: Varun, that piece of code takes normal no change. Mean to say 1px represents border width, look and feel of border and color

Comment: My Question is why you giving a border to body? why not wrapping all content within a main `div` and then give `border`. One suggestion it is a good practice to use a `shorthand method`.

Comment: @Pallavipradeep please post your code with Demo link. so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay...first it seemed strange...because jsfiddle too showed same behaviour

then i added `height` and `width` to parent wrappers :

```
html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

and it seems to work  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x95LE/2/)

Sidenote :

Give `body` `height` `width` too :

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

and then use single line style :

```
 border: 8px solid #045FB4; /* same as what u wrote in 3 lines */
```

Comment: OMG your alive! Welcome back to the land of the living.